# Print a Doctrine_Collection object?

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine

I'm currently using Symfony 1.2 and Doctrine for my project and I have a question concerning the Doctrine_collection objects.

Say I want to retrieve infos about the element with Id 1 in my table test

```
$test = Doctrine::getTable('Test')->find(1);
```

Fine it's working, I can print the different attributes of this object, no problem here

```
echo $test->name;
```

I can also print the whole object in an array

```
print_r($test->toArray());
```

But if I try to print directly the doctrine_collection object

```
print_r($test)
```

I get a huge array, with a lot of strange values like configuration parameters and stuff. Is it a normal behavior ?

Comment: yes it is ,  you are print_r `$test` which is an instance of `Doctrine_Collection` and underneath it you are looking to many doctrine properties

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, and by the way it seems than `print_r` the `Doctrine_collection` results in an infinite loop, do you have an idea why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avoid printing `Doctrine_Collection` or `Doctrine_Record`, there are many properties for internal use that do not matter to you, and you can also see relations, which can result in recursion if the related record has a reverse relation. Using `toArray()` on the collection or record is the best practice.

Comment: +1. Thanks, I could have used toArray() in the past and didn't realize it was available.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following to print the object in nice format:

```
  echo "<pre>";
  \Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($doctrineObject);
```

Comment: eh...you do realize that this question is almost 4 years old and is about doctrine 1, not doctrine 2?

Comment: still comes as a first answer on google so it's useful :)

Comment: very useful in fact